# return all strings contains given string in suffix tree

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, strings, searching, suffix-trees

Here is my question:

Given a compressed suffix tree of string S and a substring T.
I need to return all substrings of S that begins with the substring T
sorted by lexicographic order.

My approach:
I can traverse the suffix tree and find the edge / node which last letter of T is written on it.
The subtree of this edge basically should be all the substrings of S beginning with the string T.

Am I right about this one? 
And How can I print all this subtree sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You need to consume the symbols of $T$ and all occurrences of it shall be in the sub-tree below the position you stopped.

Since the edges are stored in lexicographical order, you can perform a Depth-first to print all the substrings of $S$ starting with $T$ in lexicographical order.

Using this example from Wikipedia[image]

and assuming $T = A$, we would arrive at an internal node. Doing a DFS, we would have: $A\$$, $ANA\$$, $ANANA\$$.